# FB losing session after header

Tags: php, facebook, session

I'm having an issue losing a session variable after a header redirect, I've looked around for a solution and most just involved making sure exit was called after the header declaration to ensure the session is exited.

**firstfile.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if( $_SESSION['fb_access_token']){
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', $_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
$user = $response->getGraphUser();
echo ' <script> $( document ).ready(function() {';
echo ' $("#state").text("Logged in as: "+"';
echo $user['name'] .'");';
echo '});
</script>';
header('Location: ../mysite/index.php');
EXIT;
}
```

And the second file I'm redirecting too that somehow loses the content in

```
$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] :
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

echo 'profile';
echo  $_SESSION['fb_access_token'];
if( $_SESSION['fb_access_token']){
    echo 'here';
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', $_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
$user = $response->getGraphUser();

echo ' <script> $( document ).ready(function() {';
echo ' $("#state").text("Logged in as: "+"';
echo $user['name'] .'");';
echo '});
</script>';

}
      if($_SESSION['fb_access_token'] == null){
          echo '<P/>null';
      }
?>
```

Obviously this returns just `null` as the session becomes empty so I'm not entirely sure why the session value is lost after the header method is used if I have reopened the session. Any help would be appreciated.

Note : i recently also tried modifying the php.ini due to some peoples suggestions to ensure session cookies etc were enabled and still have had no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Does that first script even work? (header() after output) And can you post the code where you set the value of $_SESSION['fb_access_token']?

Comment: the first script works completely its accessing the session from the second script where im having the problem but if its a fault because of the first script then that may be the cause but im unsure...

Comment: @Dean219 Have you tried using `session_write_close()` ?

Comment: yeh i have since tried and had session_write_close(); at the end of the first script to close off the session however it it still didnt hep reopening the session from the second page.

Comment: The script might work due to output buffering being active – but it doesn’t make sense. You either output stuff, or you redirect. Trying to output JS code and redirect at the same time makes simply no sense. // Most likely this is a problem with the session id not being passed on properly.

Comment: thanks actually just fixed it now, if you post this as an answer i will accept it.